# boost deadline timer expires not accurate in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, boost, boost-asio

I'm using very simple code to test deadline timer in iOS

The result is not accurate: 
In Desktop or Simulator, the result will be 20 or 21, in Mobile, the result
will be 24, 25, I would like to implement a library of player, so 5ms mistake
is not acceptable.

*How can I make the timer more accurate on iOS?*

Here is the code:

```
boost::thread*                                          _thread;
boost::asio::deadline_timer*                            _timer;
boost::asio::io_service                                 _io_service;
boost::posix_time::ptime                                _lastTime;

void test()
{
    _timer = new boost::asio::deadline_timer(_io_service);
    _timer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(0));
    _timer->async_wait(boost::bind(case1));
    _thread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &_io_service));
}

void case1()
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime currentTime = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

    if (_lastTime.is_not_a_date_time() == false) {
        boost::posix_time::time_duration diff = currentTime - _lastTime;
        std::cout << "run time: " << diff.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;
    }

    _lastTime = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    _timer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(20));
    _timer->async_wait(boost::bind(case1));
}
```

Comment: in Desktop or Simulator, the result will be 20 or 21,
in Mobile, the result will be 24, 25,
I would like to implement a library of player, 5ms mistake is not allowed.

Comment: What is the default **[`tolerance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTimer/tolerance)** value?

Comment: it should be trigger on every 20 ms

Comment: I asked something else though. In case it wasn't exactly clear what, feel free to click the hyperlink (in general HR timers are a trait of realtime OSes. In linux, e.g. you'd need the realtime kernel options)

Comment: sorry, I'm asking boost timer not NSTimer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use the http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/high_resolution_timer.html and `chrono::high_resolution_clock` instead:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d58a43078383d31b)**

Output is `run time: 20` without exceptions.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>

typedef boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock hrc;
using boost::chrono::duration_cast;
using boost::chrono::milliseconds;

boost::asio::io_service                              io_service_;
boost::asio::high_resolution_timer                   timer_(io_service_);
hrc::time_point lastTime_ {};

void case1(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
    hrc::time_point currentTime = hrc::now();

    if (lastTime_.time_since_epoch().count()) {
        hrc::duration diff = currentTime - lastTime_;
        std::cout << "run time: " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(diff).count() << std::endl;
    }

    lastTime_ = hrc::now();
    timer_.expires_from_now(milliseconds(20));
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(case1, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void test()
{
    timer_.expires_from_now(milliseconds(0));
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(case1, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    io_service_.run();
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

Comment: have you try this code on Mac ?
when I run this code in real device, it always return "20" or "21"
but it returns perfect on your live demo, always return "20"

Comment: @PatrickSCLin What's your point? You can't have exact timing without dedicated hardware or special-purpose OS. As long as you're not on the hardware level, you'll be subject to OS priorities. So, yeah, on a mobile processor a fluctuation of ~1ms would seem reasonable